How do I fix this error between ninja and CMake when compiling aseprite?
After doing cmake -G Ninja -DLAF_BACKEND=skia ..,
I always get this error message
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (project):
  Running
   'C:/deps/depot_tools/ninja' '--version'
  failed with:
   unknown error

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I've figured out that it has something to do with ninja, but thats about it. I haven't even been able to find a mention of this specific error anywhere on the internet and the error message isn't exactly... helpful.
I was trying to compile aseprite, and I was expecting the command to succeed, but it just kept spitting out that one error.

Does ninja work if you run it locally?  And do you have C and C++ compilers installed, since those are the next errors you're getting?

have same problem. compilers installed. I use pyenv-win
